# Can't startup databse when connected as new user

Tags: oracle

I have created a new user and I want to do startup the database, 
but this problem appears:

[image]

I gave permission but without success

Comment: Please don't use [screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530). There are a number of articles on how to ask questions here on my profile - you might want to look? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Granting sysdba won't suffice ,you need to connect as sysdba

```
     C:\sql>sqlplus / as sysdba

        SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Jun 10 13:04:50 2019

        Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


        Connected to:
        Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
        With the Partitioning, OLAP and Data Mining options


        SQL> grant sysdba to scott;

        Grant succeeded.

        SQL> select * from v$PWFILE_USERS;   

        USERNAME                       SYSDB SYSOP SYSAS
        ------------------------------ ----- ----- -----
        SYS                            TRUE  TRUE  FALSE
        SCOTT                          TRUE  FALSE FALSE

        SQL> exit
        Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
        With the Partitioning, OLAP and Data Mining options

-- Connecting without sysdba privilege      

  C:\sql>sqlplus scott/tiger    

        SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Jun 10 13:05:08 2019

        Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


        Connected to:
        Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
        With the Partitioning, OLAP and Data Mining options

        SQL> shutdown immediate;
        ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

        SQL> exit
        Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
        With the Partitioning, OLAP and Data Mining options

-- connecting with sysdba privilege     

   C:\sql>sqlplus scott/tiger as sysdba

        SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Jun 10 13:05:29 2019

        Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


        Connected to:
        Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
        With the Partitioning, OLAP and Data Mining options

        SQL> shutdown immediate;
        Database closed.
        Database dismounted.
        ORACLE instance shut down.
        SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant sysdba privileges to your user m_m_s_f18.

Log on using sys /as sysdba or as a user who has the sysdba privilege.

```
Grant sysdba to m_m_s_f18;
```

I note you are using an out of support version of Oracle 11 and an upgrade might be in order but the process of granting high privilege to users has not changed in newer editions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I executed the instruction
But the same problem appears

Comment: Do you have a password file? It would be named orapw<instance name> and might be located at /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/dbhome_1/dbs

Comment: orcl11  
instance name